# large possible regions where $\tan z , \sin z , \cos z$ are injective

Tags: analysis

$$\tan z = \frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}, \cos(z), \sin (z) \ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$

Injectivity means:  $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$

so i think all intervals of the form $[0,u< 2\pi]$ are good. And I also think this is wrong.

Dose somebody see how to find the correct regions.

Tell me. Please

V

Comment: is $z$ a real number?

Comment: Anyway, both $sin$ and $cos$ are not injective in that interval. Restrict more. Do you have any idea about their plot?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28z%29+ ; http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28z%29+

Comment: great! Now remember that monotonicity implies injectivity and find right subintervals. (Note that $sin$, $cos$ and $tan$ give different results, but I am sure that when you understand the first one, you will be able to do the remaining ones by yourself)

Comment: OK, i restrict it like this: $[Re(z) > 0,Im(z)>0]$ and the other half is $[Re(z) < 0 , Im(z)< 0 ]$

Comment: is this correct for cosz?

Comment: Hint: $\tan(z) = \tan(w)$ if and only if $\tan(z-w) = 0$.  And where does $\tan$ take the value 0?